# Remove all backslashes from PHP urldecoded string

Tags: php, str-replace, urldecode

I am trying to remove all backslashes from a url-decoded string, but it is outputting \ rather than outputting the url-decoded string with \ removed.

Please can you tell me my problem.

```
<?php
$json = $_GET['ingredients'];
echo urldecode(str_replace($json,$json, "\\"));
?>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You want to use [`stripslashes()`](http://php.net/stripslashes), because that's exactly what it is for. Also looks shorter:

```
echo urldecode(stripslashes($json));
```

You should however consider [disabling magic_quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php) rather.

Answer (score 3):

Try this instead, your arguments for str_replace are incorrect.

```
<?php
$json = $_GET['ingredients'];
echo urldecode(str_replace("\\","",$json));
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Accoring to php.net's [str_replace docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php), the first argument is what you are searching for, the second is what you are replacing with, and the third is the string you are searching in.  So, you are looking for this:

```
str_replace("\\","", $json)
```

Comment: I had to did this to get working my input: <input type="text" value="'.htmlentities(str_replace("\\","", $filter1), ENT_QUOTES).'" name="filter1">

Answer (score 1):

You're wrongly using str_replace

```
str_replace("\\","", $json)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is working for 100% correctly.

```
$attribution = str_ireplace('\r\n', '', urldecode($attribution));
```