# Remove \" from a JSON response in PHP?

Tags: php, json

"image_url":"\"http://gfgfgfg.com/wjjjj/kjjk/2014/08/LOGO-1024x1024.jpg\""

I had the above result in json response, but it shows \" in front and back of the url. I just want to remove it from the result.

I saw the `.gsub()` in Ruby, but I want to remove \" using PHP. `str_replace('\"','',$string)` does not working :

```
 $image_rul=trim(str_replace(array('=','\"'), '', $i_url));
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this,

```
$var = '"image_url":"\"http://gfgfgfg.com/wjjjj/kjjk/2014/08/LOGO-1024x1024.jpg\""';
$result =  str_replace('\"','',$var);
```

Result  = "image_url":"http://gfgfgfg.com/wjjjj/kjjk/2014/08/LOGO-1024x1024.jpg"

```
    $var = '"image_url":"\"http://gfgfgfg.com/wjjjj/kjjk/2014/08/LOGO-1024x1024.jpg\""';
    $result =  str_replace('\\','',$var);
    echo $result =  str_replace('"','',$result);
```

result =   image_url:http://gfgfgfg.com/wjjjj/kjjk/2014/08/LOGO-1024x1024.jpg

Comment: actually i mentioned that i have tried with str_replace(), but i;m not getting the result

Answer (score 1):

You can use [stripslashes](https://www.php.net/stripslashes) for this purpose.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5930828/remove-all-backslashes-from-php-urldecoded-string) for more clarification.

Comment: @keerthi `stripslashes` removes... slashes: `echo stripslashes($text);`

Comment: yes its removing slashes but when i pass that variable in json it couldn't remove that.What may the problem.